# Missing packages while creating a diagnostic analyzer using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

*To clarify: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Update 2*

I'm trying to create a diagnostic analyzer using Roslyn.

The sample code for a diagnostic analyzer (located [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/Samples/CSharp/MakeConst/Impl/DiagnosticAnalyzer.cs) declares such an analyzer in this way:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
internal class DiagnosticAnalyzer : Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzer
```

However when I try to recreate this I cannot find the class `DiagnosticAnalyzer` in `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics` (however `IDiagnosticAnalyzer` does exist in the same namespace).

Some samples here on StackOverflow instead use (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212273/c-sharp-roslyn-change-type-of-comment))

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer]
[ExportDiagnosticAnalyzer(DiagnosticId, LanguageNames.CSharp)]
internal class DiagnosticAnalyzer : ISyntaxTreeAnalyzer
```

However in this case I cannot find the `ExportDiagnosticAnalyzer` attribute. It seems I'm missing an assembly. Using NuGet I have installed the following packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable" version="1.1.20-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Metadata" version="1.0.12-alpha" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" version="0.7.4091001-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="0.7.4091001-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="0.7.4091001-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" version="0.7.4091001-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic" version="0.7.4091001-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" version="0.7.4091001-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" version="0.7.4091001-beta" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Which as far as I could find, also by inspecting `packages.config` from the samples, should be everything I need.

When I inspect my C# project's references I have referenced the following non-standard assemblies:

- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Desktop
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Desktop
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysisWorkspaces
- Microsoft.CSharp

My question is, what am I missing that I can't find all the classes I need to create a diagnostic analyzer?

Comment: Are you using VS 14 or VS 2013?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So a month or two ago we completely changed our API for doing analyzers. (Don't worry, it was worth the trouble: the new API is a *lot* nicer.) When you're looking at the current source code in CodePlex, you're seeing stuff so new that we haven't even shipped it yet on NuGet. I *strongly* recommend you use a Visual Studio "14" CTP and download the templates to match it, which will set you up in a place that should work. Trying to use current NuGet packages against old previews is going to result in sadness.

`ExportDiagnosticAnalyzer` is obsolete, the `[DiagnosticAnalyzer]` attribute is sufficient now.

Comment: This seems the correct answer. I'll upgrade to VS2014 tomorrow. Its a pet project so it doesn't really matter that its still in the CTP phase.

Comment: If it's a pet project then yeah, just use Visual Studio "14". VMs are still recommended, but it can be installed side-by-side with Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2013 no longer receives updates for interfacing between Visual Studio and Roslyn. It's still possible to use VS 2013, but you'll have to use older versions of the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/).

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Version 0.6.4033103-beta -Pre
```

If you use the above, you're at a number of disadvantages. The appropriate documentation/samples may no longer exist, and the Roslyn Reference source likely differs in subtle ways.

As Jason suggested, it might be easier to simply move to VS 14. Of course this likely prevents you from using your diagnostics within your organization until VS 14 releases (date still publicly unknown).